# Debugging Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to debug an exception:

> thumbnails.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)

I am not sure if I am missing something else involving jQuery. I added the dependency file, and that is all I believe I should need. I believe the code I included is correct as well.

I have provided some of my HTML and JavaScript code below.

from inventory.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Rob's Rock 'n' Roll Memorabilia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" />
    <script src="scripts/utils.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/thumbnails.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

from thumbnails.js

```
  $(window).ready(function () {
        initPage();
  });
```

Comment: Where is your jquery library reference ?

Comment: Also `$(window)` should be `$(document)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is loaded top to bottom, The script are also loaded in the same order and executed as soon as loaded.

Here you have loaded `thumbnails.js` first and then `jquery.js`, so `thumbnail.js` gets loaded first and it uses the jQuery's `$` object/ function and since jquery is not loaded yet `$` is not available and therefore you see this error on the page. Take care of the order of script tags in your HTML.

Secondly, I am not sure about this `Thumbnail.js`, of how it works but it is a `$(document).ready(function () { //your code here });` there is nothing as window - ready event , it could be window load event.

Answer (score 0):

Your load order is wrong. Move your JQuery script above your thumbnails script in the load order.

Answer (score 0):

The order of included scripts is wrong

I presume `util.js` , `thumbnails.js` require `jquery` to work.

but you have include `jquery` after them. `jquery` need to be included at the beginning

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/utils.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/thumbnails.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```